# How to display images using PyQt5 on a widget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am making Wafer contour map program by PyQt5. I have some problems.

```
import pandas as pd 
test = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,101), columns=range(0,101)) # empty dataframe

for i in range(0,101):  # 
    for j in range(0,101):
        if ((50-i)**2 + (50-j)**2) < 50**2:
            test.loc[i,j] = i*2+i+j
        else:
            test.loc[i,j] = 0

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
test[test == 0] = np.nan
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(test, interpolation = 'hanning', vmin = 0, cmap = 'gist_rainbow_r')
plt.colorbar()
```

I got a below image

[image]

and I would like to display this image instead of graph on PyQt5 window

My window is below like

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)



Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType(r'C:\Users\wtjang\.spyder-py3\window.ui')

import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def addmpl(self, fig):
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

    fig1 = Figure()
    ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
    ax1f1.plot(np.random.rand(5))

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.addmpl(fig1)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

how to change graph to wafer image?

I tried to

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

        fig1 = plt.imshow(test, interpolation = 'hanning', vmin = 0, cmap = 'gist_rainbow_r')


        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        main = Main()
        main.addmpl(fig1)
        main.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but I failed.

Comment: I'm making reference to "http://blog.rcnelson.com/building-a-matplotlib-gui-with-qt-designer-part-1/"

Comment: you could try replacing `ax1f1.plot(...)` with `ax1f1.imshow(...)`.

Comment: Most of the `plt.methods(...)` won't work since you are embedding a matplotlib figure in a Qt application, so prefer the object-oriented way. `ax1f1.imshow(...)` instead of `plt.imshow(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a answer. Thank your helping :)

```
ax1f1.imshow(test, interpolation = 'hanning', vmin = 0, cmap = 'gist_rainbow_r')
```